# Github's "squash and merge" merge method - what does "combine" mean?

Tags: git, github

## Context

Github's [article](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github#squashing-your-merge-commits) on merge-methods states

> Instead of seeing all of a contributor's individual commits from a topic branch, **the commits are combined into one commit** and merged into the default branch.

The method is illustrated by the following picture, where commit D and E are "combined".

[image]

## Question

What does the article mean by "combine" commits?

Please correct me if I am wrong, but as far as I understand git, the content of commit D has absolutely no relevance for the content (i.e. working tree) of the result-commit F, no?

Or in other words, in any two cases where commit E has the same content and commit D differs, commit F will look the same, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mental model seems to be that a commit is a tree of files, not a set of changes, and that's indeed how Git implements it. So in that sense, you are right that only the contents of commit E matter.

However, when viewing a commit as a set of changes, it's easier to see what "combine" means: first the changes in D are applied, then the changes in E, and the resulting set of changes becomes F.

However you view it, though, the commit messages for F will (by default) be the combination of the commit messages of D and E.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, my mental model is that a commit is a tree of files (plus metadata such as commit-message and parents). So, everything needed to restore a version of a project, not just a diff to a previous version. This seems to be true when I inspect commits and their trees with `git cat-file -p`. Good point about the commit message, my question was only about the (working) tree of the result commit F. "However, when viewing a commit as a set of changes" <- yeah but why would I view it wrong? :)

Comment: Interestingly, there's even an [article](https://github.blog/2020-12-17-commits-are-snapshots-not-diffs/) on the Github blog how commits should be viewed as snapshots, not diffs.

Comment: "yeah but why would I view it wrong?" Well, Git itself uses that model too, depending on context. For example, when merging, the _changes_ made in each commit are applied one after another. As your question demonstrated!

Answer (score 0):

The net changes from the squashed commits (`D` and `E` in the diagram) become a new single commit (`F`). Instead of putting two (or three, or four, or however many) incremental commits into `main`, we now have *one* new commit in `main` containing the sum of all changes from that other branch.

How `F` looks will depend on what happened in the other two:

- if `D` has changes at the beginning of a file, and `E` has changes at the end of the same file, then `F` will be the changes at the beginning and end of that one file
- if `D` changes one file, and `E` changes a different one, then `F` will have changes to both files
- if `D` has a lot of work, and `E` is just a typo fix, then `F` will be all that work but with the fixed typo
- if `E` overwrites everything in `D`, then `F` will just be the contents of `E`
- etc.

Comment: Can you make an example where the content (e.g. working tree when checked out) of F cannot be determined by the content of E alone? I cannot find a single example where the content of D matters.

Comment: The first three examples? While each commit is technically a discrete and complete snapshot of the repo, each commit can also be represented as a delta from its parent commit(s); this is how most pushes and pulls operate, as it's a little silly to spend time and bandwidth transferring unchanged files. Combining the commits also means that, instead of walking the tree through D and E separately, they come in as one commit; the utility there is more obvious when there are many many commits, especially if some are tiny (like the typo fix example).